# Connect to remote MariaDB host (error 1130)

Tags: server, mariadb, slave

Replication from MariaDB (master) to MySQL 5.6 (slave)

When I try to connect to remote MariaDB host on slave server, I get this error:

> ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '[slave server ip]' is not allowed to connect
>   to this MariaDB server

What's wrong?

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?  Is GTID enabled?  Did you recently change the configuration?  If so, what M-S setup worked before?

Comment: The MariaDB version is 10.1.26-MariaDB. I don't know what's GTID, I'll search it by Google. The master server is a new server which I buy recently. I just configed the firewall ports, nothing else.

Comment: Did you have a different version on the previous Master?

Comment: No, I don't have.  Now, I install the same version of MariaDB on slave server, but I still get the error.  ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host  '[slave server ip]'  is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Comment: I run "telnet 96.52.133.40 3306" and get this message:
Trying 96.52.133.40...
Connected to 96.52.133.40.
Escape character is '^]'.
HHost '72.52.133.122' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB serverConnection closed by foreign host. 

The IPs are samples, not real.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. The slave server ip address is wrong! It's ridiculous, the slave server has another ip address, and I have to grant database user for the other one.